# Elliptic curves parameters data

Tags: elliptic-curves

Is there an official database with curve parameters for common curves? Asking for *generator point*, *order*, *prime*, *a*, *b*

I found one for `secp256k1` in the *mbedtls* library.

```
static const mbedtls_mpi_uint secp256k1_p[] = {
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0x2F, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
};
static const mbedtls_mpi_uint secp256k1_a[] = {
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_2(0x00, 0x00),
};
static const mbedtls_mpi_uint secp256k1_b[] = {
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_2(0x07, 0x00),
};
static const mbedtls_mpi_uint secp256k1_gx[] = {
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0x98, 0x17, 0xF8, 0x16, 0x5B, 0x81, 0xF2, 0x59),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xD9, 0x28, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0xDB, 0xFC, 0x9B, 0x02),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0x07, 0x0B, 0x87, 0xCE, 0x95, 0x62, 0xA0, 0x55),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xAC, 0xBB, 0xDC, 0xF9, 0x7E, 0x66, 0xBE, 0x79),
};
static const mbedtls_mpi_uint secp256k1_gy[] = {
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xB8, 0xD4, 0x10, 0xFB, 0x8F, 0xD0, 0x47, 0x9C),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0x19, 0x54, 0x85, 0xA6, 0x48, 0xB4, 0x17, 0xFD),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xA8, 0x08, 0x11, 0x0E, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xA4, 0x5D),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0x65, 0xC4, 0xA3, 0x26, 0x77, 0xDA, 0x3A, 0x48),
};
static const mbedtls_mpi_uint secp256k1_n[] = {
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0x41, 0x41, 0x36, 0xD0, 0x8C, 0x5E, 0xD2, 0xBF),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0x3B, 0xA0, 0x48, 0xAF, 0xE6, 0xDC, 0xAE, 0xBA),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
    MBEDTLS_BYTES_TO_T_UINT_8(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From IANA:

- [MIKE](https://www.iana.org/assignments/mikey-payloads/mikey-payloads.xhtml#mikey-payloads-43)
- [JOSE/JSON](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-key-elliptic-curve)
- [COSE/CBOR](https://www.iana.org/assignments/cose/cose.xhtml#elliptic-curves)

From SECG.org:

- [SEC#2](https://secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf)

From me:

- [MySuiteA Algorithms](https://dannyniu.github.io/MySuiteA/algorithms.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really find the concrete parameters of these curves.

Comment: I found some here: https://www.herongyang.com/EC-Cryptography/Curve-secp256r1-for-256-Bit-ECC-Keys.html and https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf

Comment: @unalignedmemoryaccess I would've posted the reference to SEC#2, but considering it didn't provide reference to brainpool curves, and that a research anchor best be provided, I posted links to IANA pages.

Comment: https://neuromancer.sk/std/

Comment: The SEC#2 is the best one I found.

Answer (score 4):

This year (February 2023), NIST released Special Publication [SP 800-186 "Recommendations for Discrete Logarithm-based Cryptography: Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters"](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-186.pdf).  This relatively new standards should have the latest approved curves, at least according to NIST, and all their parameters.  It covers Weierstrass, Montgomery, Twisted Edwards, Koblitz, and pseudorandom curves.

Comment: Hey, it even contains Goldilocks & Brainpool (but the latter only by reference). Missed that update.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to these [other](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/109106/555) [answers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/109119/555), there are the 2005 *Brainpool curves*, which in a nutshell have been generated with the goal of being unobjectionable.

[ECC Brainpool Standard Curves and Curve Generation v. 1.0 19.10.2005](https://www.teletrust.de/fileadmin/files/oid/oid_ECC-Brainpool-Standard-curves-V1.pdf); the [same](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128160329/http://www.ecc-brainpool.org/download/Domain-parameters.pdf) and a [site mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170919023813/http://www.ecc-brainpool.org/main.htm) thru WebArchive.

[IETF informational RFC 5639](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5639)+[errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=5639) (160/192/224/256/320/384/512-bit prime field)

[IETF informational RFC 7027](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7027) (with test vectors for brainpoolP256r1/brainpoolP384r1/brainpoolP512r1)

Although critics have emerged in Daniel J. Bernstein and Tanja Lange's [SafeCurves: choosing safe curves for elliptic-curve cryptography](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) against the Brainpool curves (both random and twisted, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/109123/555)), they apply equally to the many other curves of prime order, except for [twist security](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html) which is immaterial in many applications.